# How to create a table on SQL Server 2008, and values will be subtraction from 2 other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a table (Table-diff) on SQL Server 2008 R2 which consists of subtracted values (subtraction between two other tables). For example, if `Column1=5` in `Table_1` and if `Column1=3` in `Table_2`, then it will be `Column1=2` in `Table_diff`.

I tried to solve it with regular SQL-quesies like below:

```
create table Table_diff as select a.Column1 - b.Column1 as Column1 from Table_1 a 
       left join Table_2 b
            on a.IDNumber=b.IDNumber;
```

However, regular SQL-queries don't work on SQL Server 2008. Can you give me a tips about how to solve this situation?

Comment: Regular SQL queries work just fine in SQL Server.  You simply need to use the correct syntax for the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for creating a table in SQL Server from a `select` is `select into`:

```
select a.Column1 - b.Column1 as Column1
into Table_diff
from Table_1 a left join
     Table_2 b
      on a.IDNumber=b.IDNumber;
```